What is the inspiration behind the Weirding Module in Dune (1984)?
In the David Lynch version of Dune (1984), he added a weapon that amplified sound into a concussive blast called a Weirding Module. Is there anything discussing why he thought this necessary to his vision? For context, this version of Dune was my first introduction to this universe. Once I read the books I questioned where this Weirding Module came from and why it was added.

The "Weirding Way" was one of the elements that made the Atreides troops the equal of the Sardaukar.  However, while the novel names it, there's no actual description of it in action.  So to keep the Weirding Way, Lynch would have needed a way to visually show it and a lump of exposition to explain it.  It"s a lot simpler if it's a physical device the audience can see.  Whether this is brilliant or lazy and stupid largely comes down to your opinion of the movie.  (Not an answer, since it's just a capsule summary of 1980s Usenet flamewars.)

According to the Dune fan wiki, Director David Lynch's decision to use modules was taken because he found the idea of the Weirding Way unworkable on film, stating he did not want to see "Kung-fu on sand dunes". However, why he chose to make it sonic isn't explained. https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Weirding_Module

@KlausÆ.Mogensen that’s also on the Wikipedia page for the Weirding Module. Its source it’s basically a blog post, not first hand at all

The DuneInfo founder Mark Bennett makes the same comment in the book A Masterpiece in Disarray: David Lynch's Dune. An Oral History, so apparently the author considered him a trustworthy source. The author later offers the theory that the Weirding Modules might have been influenced by Lynch's practice of Transcendental Meditation, in an interview Lynch says he doesn't remember the exact inspiration, but the author says "they are essentially sources of power activated by a single word. That sounds a lot like mantra meditation, no?" and David Lynch replies "Yeah, yeah! Exactly."

@KlausÆ.Mogensen "…he did not want to see 'Kung-fu on sand dunes'" That's so odd of him, given the scenes where Atreides troops in Lynch's Dune are shown fighting all acrobatically around the Saudarkar in places. Seems like Kung-fu on sand dunes would have worked well for him. On the other hand Lynch ain't exactly Yuen Wo-ping, so maybe his choice was for the best. :)

@Hypnosifl That is slightly disappointing that Lynch does not seem to remember his motivation. I remember the first time I read the books and kept expecting the weapon to show up and being confused when it made no appearance.

@SDH In that interview Lynch also mentions that he doesn't remember exactly how much of his inspiration for certain movie ideas was based on the book: You said “traveling without moving”? I’m not sure if that was in the book or if I made that up. It would be interesting if you found out because I made up a bunch of stuff, but it was always inspired by Frank Herbert’s book. Things like, “my own name is a killing word.” Those kinds of things. I don’t know if that was in the book, or the weirding modules dealing with sound? Yeah, I’m not sure if that was in the book.

@Hypnosifl From his own mouth. Seems like the answer if you want to make it into one.
